# What is an FE Developer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I just got a job offer to be a FE Developer, but I've never heard of that term before. Strong HTML, CSS, Javascript, jQuery, XSL skills required.

I consider myself proficient in all of those fields except for XSL and I've never heard of that term before. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Front-End Developer

Comment: I love that you got a job and you didn't understand the title.

Comment: Actually it was just an offer. I made sure to ask you all before considering it...

Answer (score 3):

Front-End Developer ... Looking at the requirements, they are expecting you to develop the GUI / Front-End of a website/web app for them.

XSL - Extensible Stylesheet Language.  This is for transforming XML to other formats like HTML.

Answer (score 2):

"Front End" means everything to do with the (web) user interface of a system, as opposed to the "Back End", which tends to mean the business processes, database access, and so on.